# Get Variables in struct by name

Tags: c#, struct

I want to get the value from variables in a struct using the name of the variables in the struct. A function should use a string to return the value of the variable with this name in a struct.

In this Example the "GetStingfromStruct" function should return "asdf". (The current Code is just some testing and returns "System.String string1").

If this problem is solved, I have another question. Is there a way to check if the struct contains a variable with the name of the string. (To avoid Errors)

```
private void SetStruct()
{
    Mystruct mystruct = new Mystruct();
    mystruct.string1="asdf";
    mystruct.string2="ghjkl";
    mystruct.string3="qwert";
}

private sting GetStingfromStruct(string variableName)
{
    return mystruct.GetType().GetField("string1")
}

public struct Mystruct
{
    public string string1;
    public string string2;
    public string string3;
}
```

Comment: You have described a [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0).

Comment: What makes you think you need to do it in a struct? Like GSerg said, you want a dictionary.

Comment: [Collections and Data Structures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/)

Comment: Generally, when asking about adding a capability to code it's expected to compile: `sting` vs. `string`, `mystruct` is not defined in `GetStingfromStruct()`, and a missing semicolon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The minimum change to make is to pass the instance (`mystruct`) to the `GetValue` method:

```
private sting GetStingfromStruct(string variableName)
{
    return (string)mystruct.GetType().GetField(variableName).GetValue(mystruct);
}
```

You should also add checks to make sure the string value is actually a field name, etc.

But I would echo other comments and answers that this is not a great design unless you're *forced* to use a struct for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring an instance of struct inside set struct method, which you are then trying to access in a get struct method which has no access to said instance. This will not work. Why are you trying to use getters and setters for this struct? Why are you trying to use a struct when you could use a dictionary?

A dictionary could be used as follows :

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "key1", "value1" },
    { "key2", "value2" }
};
```

Comment: The SetStruct function was just an Example. It's get from a file.
But thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You can use *reflection*:

In *general case*, for an *arbitrary* struct and *arbitrary* field you can put

```
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;

    ...

    // returns field value by variableName
    // or null if field is not found
    private static string GetStringFromStruct<T>(T source, string variableName) 
      where T : struct =>
        typeof(T)
          .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | 
                     BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
          .Where(field => field.Name == variableName)
          .Select(field => field.GetValue(field.IsStatic ? null : source))
          .FirstOrDefault() 
         ?.ToString();
```

Then you can use it as

```
string result = GetStringFromStruct(mystruct, "string1");
```

If you want to inspect `mystruct` only, and don't want to use `Dictionary<string, string>` instead:

```
private sting GetStringfromStruct(string variableName)
{
    var field = mystruct.GetType().GetField(variableName);

    if (field == null)
      return null; // variableName has not found

    return field.GetValue(mystruct)?.ToString(); 
}
```